# Rational function sequence product

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, rational-functions

I want to know a closed formula for $$\prod_{m = 0}^{n} \frac{m^2 + a}{m^2 + a + 1},$$ *a* being any given complex.

When the exponent is 1, it's pretty trivial, because of cancellations, but with other positive integers, I can't figure this out.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a closed form?

Comment: There is a closed form in terms of gamma functions, but I'm not too sure if it's terribly useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(might as well...)

We can factor the numerator and denominator like so:

$$\prod_{m = 0}^{n} \frac{m^2 + a}{m^2 + a + 1}=\frac{\left(\prod\limits_{m = 0}^{n}\left(m+i\sqrt{a}\right)\right)\left(\prod\limits_{m = 0}^{n}\left(m-i\sqrt{a}\right)\right)}{\left(\prod\limits_{m = 0}^{n}\left(m+i\sqrt{1+a}\right)\right)\left(\prod\limits_{m = 0}^{n}\left(m-i\sqrt{1+a}\right)\right)}$$

and recall the definition for [Pochhammer symbols](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.E4):

$$(a)_{n+1}=\prod_{m = 0}^{n}(a+m)$$

which yields the expression

$$\prod_{m = 0}^{n} \frac{m^2 + a}{m^2 + a + 1}=\frac{\left(i\sqrt{a}\right)_{n+1}\left(-i\sqrt{a}\right)_{n+1}}{\left(i\sqrt{1+a}\right)_{n+1}\left(-i\sqrt{1+a}\right)_{n+1}}$$

or, using the [recursion relation](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/16/02/0003/) $(a)_{m+n}=(a)_m (a+m)_n$,

$$\frac{\left(i\sqrt{a}\right)_{n+1}\left(-i\sqrt{a}\right)_{n+1}}{\left(i\sqrt{1+a}\right)_{n+1}\left(-i\sqrt{1+a}\right)_{n+1}}=\frac{a\left(1+i\sqrt{a}\right)_n\left(1-i\sqrt{a}\right)_n}{(1+a)\left(1+i\sqrt{1+a}\right)_n\left(1-i\sqrt{1+a}\right)_n}$$

We could then use the relation between gamma functions and Pochhammer symbols:

$$(a)_n=\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)}$$

such that the whole mess is in terms of gamma functions like in Robert's answer. From that, we could then apply the reflection relation

$$\Gamma(1+iy)\Gamma(1-iy)=\pi y\;\mathrm{csch}(\pi y)$$

to have an expression with the minimum number of gamma functions and hyperbolic functions; I will skip that since Robert seems to have covered that, and will instead draw attention to the fact that if $a$ is of the form $a=-\ell^2$ or $a=-\ell^2-1$ for $\ell$ a positive integer, the gamma functions become singular and we have to stick with the Pochhammer symbol representation. In this respect, one could use the [special formula for Pochhammer symbols with negative integer argument](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/27/01/0004/):

$$(-\ell)_n=(-1)^n n!\binom{\ell}{n}=(-1)^n (\ell-n+1)_n$$

so for instance, if $a=-\ell^2$,

$$\frac{\left(i\sqrt{-\ell^2}\right)_{n+1}\left(-i\sqrt{-\ell^2}\right)_{n+1}}{\left(i\sqrt{1-\ell^2}\right)_{n+1}\left(-i\sqrt{1-\ell^2}\right)_{n+1}}=\frac{\left(-\ell\right)_{n+1}\left(\ell\right)_{n+1}}{\left(-\sqrt{\ell^2-1}\right)_{n+1}\left(\sqrt{\ell^2-1}\right)_{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\left(\ell-n\right)_{n+1}\left(\ell\right)_{n+1}}{\left(-\sqrt{\ell^2-1}\right)_{n+1}\left(\sqrt{\ell^2-1}\right)_{n+1}}$$

and similarly for the case $a=-\ell^2-1$...

Answer (score 6):

$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(\sqrt{-a-1}\right) \Gamma\left(-\sqrt{-a-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sqrt{-a}\right) \Gamma\left(-\sqrt{-a}\right)}
\frac{\Gamma\left(n+1+\sqrt{-a}\right) \Gamma\left(n+1-\sqrt{-a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1+\sqrt{-a-1}\right) \Gamma\left(n+1-\sqrt{-a-1}\right)}
$$

Comment: [Some of those gamma functions can be turned into hyperbolic sines if need be.](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E3)